# Is "pam_unix(cron:session): session opened" misformulated?

Tags: security, sudo, pam

```
$ journalctl -g sudo -S today
Jan 21 00:02:02 limbo sudo[3898480]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by seca(uid=1001)
Jan 21 00:02:02 limbo sudo[3898480]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

The problem is that user `seca` is non-root and should not be able to do this:

```
seca@limbo:~$ sudo echo oopsie
[sudo] password for seca:         
Sorry, user seca is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/echo oopsie' as root on limbo.
```

So, is the message misformulated or is there some other reason? Should it be something like "an attempt to open session has been made"?

Of course, this wording has been there for long time and no one is going to change it. I'm just trying to figure out if there is anything weird going on in my system.

Linux Mint 21.2 in case it's important.

Comment: The error from sudo just says that they're not allowed to run that specific command as root. They might be allowed to run other commands. Try`sudo -l` as that user.

Comment: @muru So, your hypothesis is that the session is indeed authorized and something does run as root for this non-root user?

Answer (score 0):

The message makes sense to me b/c it opened a session, then said, "no way," then closed it.  If anything, the message should report the command the user attempted to run.  My $0.02.

Comment: The problem is that my journal contains similar messages for the user who does have root access. I even went so paranoid that I got the log with microsecond precision and there is no difference in session duration either: about 100 ms both. Exploring @muru 's advice now.